# ThreadPoolExecutor check if certain Task is in queue

Tags: java, future, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, futuretask

I have a serial connection which shall only be used by a single thread. But before I submit a new Task to the executors I want check if that certain Task is already in the queu(e.g for polling values).

```
executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    TaskRunnable runn = new TaskRunnable(
                            Integer.toString(i), "42");
                    if (!executor.getQueue().contains(runn)) {
                        executor.submit(runn);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();


public void write(String addr, String value) {
    // write
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class TaskRunnable implements Runnable {
    String addr, value;

    public TaskRunnable(String addr, String value) {
        this.addr = addr;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        write(addr, value);
        System.out.println("Executed: " + addr + " - "
                + executor.getQueue().size());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TaskRunnable other = (TaskRunnable) obj;
        return this.addr.equals(other.addr);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.addr != null ? this.addr.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

}
```

If I check `executor.getQueue()` the type is `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` but if I do `executor.getQueue().contains(task)` the equals method of `TaskRunnable` is called with an object of type `FutureTask` and I get this exception

```
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to ExecutorTest$TaskRunnable
```

Any Idea how I can check If a certain `TaskRunnable` is already in the queue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the Future returned from `executor.submit(runn);`. You can then ask if the queue contains the Future.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `executor.submit(Runnable)` to `executor.execute(Runnable);` it should then not repack your Runnable into it's own task.